# margin-left its not working

Tags: html, css

I'm still a beginner in css, and I'm trying to give some margin-left to my paragraph and `<h2>` but its not working.

I have a div with 700px  and I want to give 10px of margin-left for my `<p>` and `<h2>` in relation to the image.

But its not working, can you give some help?

What Im trying:

**My jsfiddle** with the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/2p9vw/5/

**My html:**

```
<div id="example">
    <img src="images/image3.jpg" width="226" height="129" />
    <h2>Example</h2>
    <p>text here  text here  text here  text here  text here  text here  text here  text here  text here  text here  </p>
</div>
```

**My css:**

```
#example {width:690px; height:auto; font-size:16px; margin:15px 0 0 0;}
#example img{float:left;}
#example h2{float:right;margin-left:10px; font-size:16px; color:#444;}
#example p{ text-align:justify; margin-left:10px; }
```

Comment: Thanks for your correction, it was example there!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a div with 700px and I want to give 10px of margin-left for my `<p>` and `<h2>` in relation to the image.
>
> But its not working

It *is* working – you just don’t *see* it working.

Since your image is floated, that means any *inline content* will float around it – but the block elements like p and h2 still go over the *full* width, *underneath* your image – and that’s why you don’t see any effect of that margin, because it is “under” the image.

Simply give your image a `margin-right` of 10px instead. http://jsfiddle.net/2p9vw/4/

Comment: Thank you for your very good explanation :). It was very enlightening!