# margin left not working when elements are floated and are block elements

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin-left

I have an image (`img` tag) and a div, whose `display` property is set to `flex`.
`div` and `img` are placed in a row. They are floated.
I want to apply `margin-left` to the div but it does not work, unless I set the display property of the `div` to `inline-block`.
I've explored StackoverFlow, the nearest post to my case is this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23331008/margin-left-its-not-working#answer-23331038). But that so post does not make me understand what's going on.
As it can be seen in the image below, the margin of div on the left, overlaps with the image. Why? why isn't it pushing the div to right?: [image]

Here is my code:
html

```
<div id="traffic">
  <p>Traffic</p>
  <img  id="chart" src="https://www.syncfusion.com/products/flutter/control/images/chart/chart-types/flutter-multiple-axis-charts.png" alt="" srcset="">
  <div id="traffic-infos"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
#traffic {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow: auto;  /* so the container resized its height */
}

#traffic-infos {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 40px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: black;

}
#chart{
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 850px;
  min-width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

the same code in JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shahryarslg/xmo5uahv/8/

The whole problem is solved if I change the `display` of `traffic-infos` class to `inline-block`. But I want to understand how `display` is related to this problem? what's going on?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added this value margin-left: 100px; instead of the existing one which was margin-left: 40px; and added a border solid red for the div element. See how it works below . It seems  the div element pushes to the right more . This may gives you a hint

Comment: below? below where? @AlanM

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the margin on the floated element:

```
#chart {
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

Comment: I did know that I can set margin on the image and it will work. My question is WHY it is not working if I set margin on the `div` element beside the image.